# Корректна ли фраза?

Tags: стилистика

Корректна ли фраза «пересказывать иными словами великие идеи своих великих предшественников»?

Answer (score 1):

Тут тавтология: два раза слово "великий". Лучше будет сказать "знаменитых предков".

Answer (score 0):

Грамматически корректна, стилистичски - в общем-то тоже, хотя для "идей" хочется подобрать какой-то другой глагол. Может, "излагать"?

Comment: Если "великие идеи своих великих предшественников", то и сам пересказчик якобы претендует на величие. Некорректность — в застенчивости и сокрытии скромности. :))

Comment: ну да, да... Только вопрос такой старый, что относится ко времени, когда я только осваивался тут, не до жиру было. Приветствую, кстати)))